# Options for indexing a view with cte

Tags: sql-server, view, common-table-expression, materialized

I have a view for which I want to create an Indexed view. After a lot of energy I was able to put the sql query in place for the view and It looks like this -

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[FriendBalances] WITH SCHEMABINDING  as
WITH

trans (Amount,PaidBy,PaidFor, Id)  AS    

(SELECT Amount,userid AS PaidBy, PaidForUsers_FbUserId AS PaidFor, Id FROM dbo.Transactions
FULL JOIN dbo.TransactionUser ON dbo.Transactions.Id = dbo.TransactionUser.TransactionsPaidFor_Id),

bal (PaidBy,PaidFor,Balance) AS

(SELECT PaidBy,PaidFor, SUM( Amount/ transactionCounts.[_count]) AS Balance FROM trans 
JOIN (SELECT Id,COUNT(*)AS _count FROM trans GROUP BY Id)   AS transactionCounts ON trans.Id = transactionCounts.Id AND trans.PaidBy <> trans.PaidFor
GROUP BY trans.PaidBy,trans.PaidFor )
SELECT ISNULL(bal.PaidBy,bal2.PaidFor)AS PaidBy,ISNULL(bal.PaidFor,bal2.PaidBy)AS PaidFor,
ISNULL( bal.Balance,0)-ISNULL(bal2.Balance,0) AS Balance
FROM bal 
left JOIN bal AS bal2 ON bal.PaidBy = bal2.PaidFor AND bal.PaidFor = bal2.Paidby   
WHERE ISNULL( bal.Balance,0)>ISNULL(bal2.Balance,0)
```

Sample Data for FriendBalances View -

```
PaidBy  PaidFor  Balance
------  -------  -------
9990    9991     1000
9990    9992     2000
9990    9993     1000
9991    9993     1000
9991    9994     1000
```

It is mainly a join of 2 tables.

`Transactions` -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [float] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Remarks] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [GroupFbGroupId] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Sample data in `Transactions` Table -

```
Id  Date                     Amount  UserId  Remarks         GroupFbGroupId
--  -----------------------  ------  ------  --------------  --------------
1   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000  3000    9990    this is a test  NULL
2   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000  3000    9990    this is a test  NULL
3   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000  3000    9991    this is a test  NULL
```

`TransactionUsers` -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransactionUser](
    [TransactionsPaidFor_Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PaidForUsers_FbUserId] [bigint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample Data in `TransactionUser` Table -

```
TransactionsPaidFor_Id  PaidForUsers_FbUserId
----------------------  ---------------------
1                       9991
1                       9992
1                       9993
2                       9990
2                       9991
2                       9992
3                       9990
3                       9993
3                       9994
```

Now I am not able to create a view because my query contains cte(s). What are the options that I have now?

If cte can be removed, what should be the other option which would help in creating indexed views.

Here is the error message -

> `Msg 10137, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot create index on view "ShareBill.Test.Database.dbo.FriendBalances" because it references common table expression "trans". Views referencing common table expressions cannot be indexed. Consider not indexing the view, or removing the common table expression from the view definition.`

The concept: 
Transaction mainly consists of:

- an Amount that was paid
- `UserId` of the User who paid that amount
- and some more information which is not important for now.

`TransactionUser` table is a mapping between a Transaction and a User Table. Essentially a transaction can be shared between multiple persons. So we store that in this table.

So we have transactions where 1 person is paying for it and other are sharing the amount. So if A pays 100$ for B then B would owe 100$ to A. Similarly if B pays 90$ for A then B would owe only $10 to A. Now if A pays 300$ for A,b,c that means B would owe 110$ and C would owe 10$ to A.

So in this particular view we are aggregating the effective amount that has been paid (if any) between 2 users and thus know how much a person owes another person.

Comment: Not being able to create a view from a statement just because it contains a CTE smells wrong to me. What error do you get when you try to create the view?

Comment: I have added the error message. It refers to the cte trans.

Comment: It looks like there's going to be several other stumbling blocks to making this an indexed view, not just removing the CTEs. Could you post some sample data (say 20 rows or so, ideally as `INSERT` statements) for the tables, the expected results from the view, and explain the results?

Comment: Having seen your example and looked through your query again - there's too much going on that you won't be able to create an indexed view based on your current tables - there's no way to avoid needing to know how many rows are in `TransactionUser`, which implies a `COUNT(*)` somewhere - but you're not allowed CTEs (as you know) nor subqueries, nor to base one indexed view on another, so there's no way to use the result of that `COUNT(*)` any further. There may be a way if we redesign the base tables. I'll have a think, if that'd be useful to you?

Comment: Damien, that would be really helpful!
Just to give a heads up on what I don't want - I  don't want to create separate tables which would essentially be a replacement for the view. The reason being that, I would then have to worry about writing and maintaining code which would be used to update this particular table whenever there is a change in Transaction table or TransactionUser table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, this gives you an indexed view (that needs an additional view on top of to sort out the who-owes-who detail), but it may not satisfy your requirements still.

```
/* Transactions table, as before, but with handy unique constraint for FK Target */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [float] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Remarks] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [GroupFbGroupId] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
 constraint UQ_Transactions_XRef UNIQUE (Id,Amount,UserId)
)
```

Nothing surprising so far, I hope

```
/* Much expanded TransactionUser table, we'll hide it away and most of the maintenance is automatic */
CREATE TABLE [dbo]._TransactionUser(
    [TransactionsPaidFor_Id] int NOT NULL,
    [PaidForUsers_FbUserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    Amount float not null,
    PaidByUserId bigint not null,
    UserCount int not null,
    LowUserID as CASE WHEN [PaidForUsers_FbUserId] < PaidByUserId THEN [PaidForUsers_FbUserId] ELSE PaidByUserId END,
    HighUserID as CASE WHEN [PaidForUsers_FbUserId] < PaidByUserId THEN PaidByUserId ELSE [PaidForUsers_FbUserId] END,
    PerUserDelta as (Amount/UserCount) * CASE WHEN [PaidForUsers_FbUserId] < PaidByUserId THEN -1 ELSE 1 END,
    constraint PK__TransactionUser PRIMARY KEY ([TransactionsPaidFor_Id],[PaidForUsers_FbUserId]),
    constraint FK__TransactionUser_Transactions FOREIGN KEY ([TransactionsPaidFor_Id]) references dbo.Transactions,
    constraint FK__TransactionUser_Transaction_XRef FOREIGN KEY ([TransactionsPaidFor_Id],Amount,PaidByUserID)
        references dbo.Transactions (Id,Amount,UserId) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

This table now maintains enough information to allow the view to be constructed. The rest of the work we do is to construct/maintain the data in the table. Note that, with the foreign key constraint, we've already ensured that if, say, an amount is changed in the transactions table, everything gets recalculated.

```
/* View that mimics the original TransactionUser table -
in fact it has the same name so existing code doesn't need to change */
CREATE VIEW dbo.TransactionUser
with schemabinding
as
    select
        [TransactionsPaidFor_Id],
        [PaidForUsers_FbUserId]
    from
        dbo._TransactionUser
GO
/* Effectively the PK on the original table */
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_TransactionUser on dbo.TransactionUser ([TransactionsPaidFor_Id],[PaidForUsers_FbUserId])
```

Anything that's already written to work against `TransactionUser` will now work against this view, and be none the wiser. Except, they can't insert/update/delete the rows without some help:

```
/* Now we write the trigger that maintains the underlying table */
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.T_TransactionUser_IUD
ON dbo.TransactionUser
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    /* Every delete affects *every* row for the same transaction
    We need to drop the counts on every remaining row, as well as removing the actual rows we're interested in */
    WITH DropCounts as (
        select TransactionsPaidFor_Id,COUNT(*) as Cnt from deleted group by TransactionsPaidFor_Id
    ), KeptRows as (
        select tu.TransactionsPaidFor_Id,tu.PaidForUsers_FbUserId,UserCount - dc.Cnt as NewCount
        from dbo._TransactionUser tu left join deleted d
            on tu.TransactionsPaidFor_Id = d.TransactionsPaidFor_Id and
                tu.PaidForUsers_FbUserId = d.PaidForUsers_FbUserId
            inner join DropCounts dc
                on
                    tu.TransactionsPaidFor_Id = dc.TransactionsPaidFor_Id
        where
            d.PaidForUsers_FbUserId is null
    ), ChangeSet as (
        select TransactionsPaidFor_Id,PaidForUsers_FbUserId,NewCount,1 as Keep
        from KeptRows
        union all
        select TransactionsPaidFor_Id,PaidForUsers_FbUserId,null,0
        from deleted
    )
    merge into dbo._TransactionUser tu
    using ChangeSet cs on tu.TransactionsPaidFor_Id = cs.TransactionsPaidFor_Id and tu.PaidForUsers_FbUserId = cs.PaidForUsers_FbUserId
    when matched and cs.Keep = 1 then update set UserCount = cs.NewCount
    when matched then delete;

    /* Every insert affects *every* row for the same transaction
    This is why the indexed view couldn't be generated */
    WITH TU as (
        select TransactionsPaidFor_Id,PaidForUsers_FbUserId,Amount,PaidByUserId from dbo._TransactionUser
        where TransactionsPaidFor_Id in (select TransactionsPaidFor_Id from inserted)
        union all
        select TransactionsPaidFor_Id,PaidForUsers_FbUserId,Amount,UserId
        from inserted i inner join dbo.Transactions t on i.TransactionsPaidFor_Id = t.Id
    ), CountedTU as (
        select TransactionsPaidFor_Id,PaidForUsers_FbUserId,Amount,PaidByUserId,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TransactionsPaidFor_Id) as Cnt
        from TU
    )
    merge into dbo._TransactionUser tu
    using CountedTU new on tu.TransactionsPaidFor_Id = new.TransactionsPaidFor_Id and tu.PaidForUsers_FbUserId = new.PaidForUsers_FbUserId
    when matched then update set Amount = new.Amount,PaidByUserId = new.PaidByUserId,UserCount = new.Cnt
    when not matched then insert
        ([TransactionsPaidFor_Id],[PaidForUsers_FbUserId],Amount,PaidByUserId,UserCount)
    values (new.TransactionsPaidFor_Id,new.PaidForUsers_FbUserId,new.Amount,new.PaidByUserId,new.Cnt);
```

Now that the underlying table is being maintained, we can finally write the indexed view you wanted in the first place... almost. The issue is that the totals we create may be positive or negative, because we've normalized the transactions so that we can easily sum them:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo]._FriendBalances
WITH SCHEMABINDING
as
    SELECT
        LowUserID,
        HighUserID,
        SUM(PerUserDelta) as Balance,
        COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt
    FROM dbo._TransactionUser
    WHERE LowUserID != HighUserID
    GROUP BY
        LowUserID,
        HighUserID
GO
create unique clustered index IX__FriendBalances on dbo._FriendBalances (LowUserID, HighUserID)
```

So we finally create a view, built on the indexed view above, that if the balance is negative, we flip the person owed, and the person owing around. But it will use the index on the above view, which is most of the work we were seeking to save by having the indexed view:

```
create view dbo.FriendBalances
as
    select
        CASE WHEN Balance >= 0 THEN LowUserID ELSE HighUserID END as PaidBy,
        CASE WHEN Balance >= 0 THEN HighUserID ELSE LowUserID END as PaidFor,
        ABS(Balance) as Balance
    from
        dbo._FriendBalances WITH (NOEXPAND)
```

Now, finally, we insert your sample data:

```
set identity_insert dbo.Transactions on --Ensure we get IDs we know
GO
insert into dbo.Transactions (Id,[Date] ,   Amount , UserId , Remarks ,GroupFbGroupId)
select 1   ,'2001-01-01T00:00:00.000', 3000,    9990    ,'this is a test',  NULL union all
select 2   ,'2001-01-01T00:00:00.000', 3000,    9990    ,'this is a test',  NULL union all
select 3   ,'2001-01-01T00:00:00.000', 3000,    9991    ,'this is a test',  NULL
GO
set identity_insert dbo.Transactions off
GO
insert into dbo.TransactionUser (TransactionsPaidFor_Id,  PaidForUsers_FbUserId)
select 1,   9991 union all
select 1,   9992 union all
select 1,   9993 union all
select 2,   9990 union all
select 2,   9991 union all
select 2,   9992 union all
select 3,   9990 union all
select 3,   9993 union all
select 3,   9994
```

And query the final view:

```
select * from dbo.FriendBalances

PaidBy  PaidFor Balance
9990    9991    1000
9990    9992    2000
9990    9993    1000
9991    9993    1000
9991    9994    1000
```

---

Now, there is additional work we *could* do, if we were concerned that someone may find a way to dodge the triggers and perform direct changes to the base tables. The first would be *yet another* indexed view, that will ensure that every row for the same transaction has the *same* `UserCount` value. Finally, with a few additional columns, check constraints, FK constraints and more work in the triggers, I *think* we can ensure that the `UserCount` is correct - but it may add more overhead than you want.

I can add scripts for these aspects if you want me to - it depends on how restrictive you want/need the database to be.

Comment: Damien, Thanks a lot. Give me some time to understand it.